# My display-name won't sync with my Live.com name

Tags: display-name

Unbeknownst to me, I had a generic, bogus name specified on my Live.com account.  Today, I accepted an invite to join a company’s Sharepoint, and I logged-in using my Live.com credentials.

Once I logged-in, I noticed my bogus name in the upper, right-hand corner of Sharepoint.  I wasn’t able to edit the name from within Sharepoint, so I edited it inside of Live.com.  Now that I have my valid name inside of Live.com, I’ve signed back in to the company’s Sharepoint site, but my name is still the generic, bogus value that I used to have.

Will this eventually synchronize or does some additional Admin work need done on the Sharepoint side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this by having users add their correct name to Windows Live and completely log out of SharePoint. We then removed the user from any groups and the overall site directory. Then we sent a new invitation to join SharePoint. After that the new name appeared in SharePoint.

Answer (score 3):

No, the Live-ID attributes won't sync once their in Office 365 as external users. The only way to change the name is to delete (revoke) the external Live-ID user in SharePoint Online and send a new invitation link.

This will force the one-time data collection of your Live-ID properties, such as DisplayName.

> By default, you are not able to work with the attributes of a Live ID directly in SharePoint Online.  If you would like to control the user profile attributes of external users, it is recommend that you assign them a SharePoint Online licenses and user id.  Since there was never an intention to have customers edit Live ID attributes, I do not have a list of those attributes.

Reference: [Populating SharePoint Online Profile](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/50110.aspx)